# Regex how to replace <'string'> with a new line but keep the 'string'

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I am completely clueless on how to use regex and need some help on the problem above. I need to replace `<>` with new lines but keep the string between `<>`. So

```
<'sample text'><'sample text 2'>
```

becomes

```
'sample text'
'sample text2'
```

Comment: What is the language you're using? Also, do you need new line for first `<` and last `>` ?

Comment: Just replace `><` with a newline, no regular expression needed.

Comment: The general answer about how to keep parts of a string when doing a regular expression replacement of other parts is to use a capture group for the parts you want to keep, and back-references in the replacement.

Comment: how should look the result for this input `<'sample text'> <'sample text 2'> some text    <'sample text 3'> <>` ?

Comment: For niitaku its using powershell and the first and last group of <> shouldn't have new lines. For barmar i will try and see if it works with the text file i am using. RomanPerekhrest it should look like 
'sample text'
*new line*'sample text 2' some text
*new line*'sample text 3'
*new line*"empty line"

Comment: @Adlis, there's a contradiction between your first expected result `'sample text' \n
'sample text2'` and the last one `sample text' 'sample text 2' some text 'sample text 3' "empty line"`

Comment: woops i missed that should be sample text \n sample text 2 \n some text sample text 3 \n empty \n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\<([^>]*)\>
```

This regex will capture the text between `<` and `>` into a capture groups, which you can then reference again and put a newline between them.

```
\1\n
```

Check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/Lj4Bw0/3).

EDIT:

In PowerShell

```
PS C:\Users\shtabriz> $string = "<'sample text'><'sample text 2'>"
PS C:\Users\shtabriz> $regex = "\<([^>]*)\>"
PS C:\Users\shtabriz> [regex]::Replace($string, $regex, '$1'+"`n")
'sample text'
'sample text 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Textpad:

Example:

### String:

" 1) Navigate to record. 2) Navigate to the tab and select. 3) Click the field. 4) Click on the tab and scroll."

Note: For search/replace blow, do NOT include the quotes, I used them to show the presence of a space in the search term

Search: "[0-9]+) "
Replace: "\n$0"

### Resulting String:

1. Navigate to record.
2. Navigate to the tab and select.
3. Click the field.
4. Click on the tab and scroll.

(note... stackoverflow changed my ")" to a ".")

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Shawn Tabrizi's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42010470/45375) with a more **PowerShell-idiomatic solution** and some background information:

PowerShell surfaces the functionality of the .NET [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) method (`[regex]::Replace()`, from PowerShell) via its own **[`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375)**.

The most concise solution (but see below for potential pitfalls):

```bash
# Note the escaped "$" ("`$")
"<'sample text'><'sample text 2'>" -replace '<(.*?)>', "`$1`n"
```

Output:

```bash
'sample text'
'sample text 2'
```

- `$1` is a [*numbered capture-group substitution*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-a-numbered-group), referring to what the 1st (and only) capture group inside the regex (`(...)`) captured, which are the strings between `<` and `>` (`.*?` is a *non-greedy* expression that matches any run of characters but stops once the next construct, `>` in this case, is found).

  - However, inside a ***double*-quoted string (`"..."`)**, also known as an [*expandable string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), `$1` would be interpreted as a *PowerShell variable reference*, so the **`$` character must be *escaped*** in order to be preserved, using the backtick (`` ` ``), PowerShell's general escape character: `` "`$1" ``
  - Conversely, **if you want the *.NET API* not to interpret a `$` character in the substitution string, use `$$`** (either `$$` inside `'...'`, or `` "`$`$" `` inside `"..."`) - but note that inside the *regex* operand a verbatim `$` must be escaped as `\$`.
- `` "`n" `` is a PowerShell escape sequence that can be used inside expandable strings (only) - see the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic.

**Caveat**:

- While convenient here, there are **pitfalls with respect to using  *expandable* strings as the regexes and substitution operands**, as it isn't always obvious what PowerShell expands (interpolates) up front, and what the .NET API ends up seeing as a result.
- Therefore, it is **generally preferable to use *single*-quoted strings** (`'...'`, also known as *verbatim strings*) - both for the substitution operand and the regex itself, and - if needed - use an *expression* (`(...)`) to build the overall string, which allows you to separate the verbatim (pass-through) parts from interpolated parts.

This is what Shawn did in his answer; translated to a `-replace` operation:

```bash
# Note the expression used to build the substitution string
# from a verbatim ('...') and an interpolated ("...") part.
"<'sample text'><'sample text 2'>" -replace '<(.*?)>', ('${1}' + "`n")
```

Another option, using `-f`, the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f):

```bash
"<'sample text'><'sample text 2'>" -replace '<(.*?)>', ("{0}`n" -f '${1}')
```

Note the **use of `${1}` instead of just `$1`**: Enclosing the number / name of the referenced capture group in `{...}` ***disambiguates* it from the characters that follow**, which avoids another pitfall, as the following example shows (incidentally, PowerShell's own variable references can be disambiguated the same way):

```bash
# FAILS and results in 'f$142', because the .NET API sees
# '$142' as the substitution string, and there is no 142nd capture group.
$suffix = '42'; 'foo' -replace '(oo)', ('$1' + $suffix)

# OK, with disambiguation via {...} -> 'foo42'
$suffix = '42'; 'foo' -replace '(oo)', ('${1}' + $suffix)
```